# C++ Code Not Compiling in NetBeans 8.0 (possible issue with msys mkdir)

Tags: c++, netbeans, mkdir, mingw32, msys

I've been searching the stack and google for solutions to my problem, but I haven't found any that work. I'm trying to compile some sample code that came with NetBeans to test it out, but I'm getting nowhere. I keep getting the following error

```
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Damian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/InputOutput_1'
"/C/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/inputoutput_1.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/Damian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/InputOutput_1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src
make.exe[2]: mkdir: Command not found
make.exe[2]: *** [build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/src/io.o] Error 127
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Damian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/InputOutput_1'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/Damian/Documents/NetBeansProjects/InputOutput_1'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 2s)
```

My NetBeans setup is as follows:

> **Base Directory:** C:\MinGW\bin 
> **C Compiler:**
>   C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe 
> **C++ Compiler:**
>   C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe 
> **Fortran Compiler:**
>   C:\MinGW\bin\gfortran.exe 
> **Assembler:**
>   C:\MinGW\bin\as.exe 
> **Make Command:**
>   C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe 
> **Debbuger Command:**
>   C:\MinGW\bin\gdb.exe

And I have set the PATH environment variables accordingly:

**PATH --> C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;**

I've also made sure that mkdir.exe is actually in "C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin".

```
>mkdir test123

##The result is folder "test123" being created in whatever 
##directory I was running the command prompt from
```

I did notice that the **-p** flag is being applied when mkdir is being executed, so I tried that in the command prompt and it returned the following error:

```
C:\Users\Damian>mkdir -P A/A/A/A
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

Has anyone run into a similar issue? I used the "mingw-get-setup.exe" from http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/ if that's relevant at all. I can't think of anything else, I don't know why the -p flag isn't working. I looked up it's function, and it's for making nested folders. Either way you can't make nested folders with or without the -p flag using mkdir. You just get the error "The syntax of the command is incorrect."

Not sure if it's of any use, but I'm running Windows 8.1 (64bit). I have also tried using the mingw-w64 fork of mingw32 (*i.e.* http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/), but I get the same error.

Comment: `mkdir` is also a windows built-in command, and your command prompt tests are calling that, so they don't prove anything.

Comment: Also, if you set `PATH` in your system settings *after* NetBeans is already up and running, you may want to try restarting it.

Comment: True, although I did try running it from the directory mkdir is in, but I guess I should have figured windows mkdir takes precedence unless I call msys mkdir directly. I restarted NetBeans at least 6 times last night, but it didn't help at the time. Turned on my PC this morning and everything was working. It's strange since I set my environment variables via the main properties dialogue, not the cmd prompt which I read requires a restart. I guess NetBeans must be closed when they are set? Either way, the issue is resolved. This question can be closed or deleted.

Comment: Maybe this answer help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972091/netbeans-error-for-msys-for-mingw/49267461#49267461

Answer (score 0):

Your settings are correct.
This can happen if you have set the settings on netbeans before/during the time of installing MINGW. Just restart netbeans