# Netbeans error for MSYS for MINGW

Tags: netbeans, mingw, netbeans-8

I have installed Netbeans as well as MinGW along with the MSYS, still I am having the below error when build and run

```
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
make.exe": /bin/sh: Command not found
make.exe": /bin/sh: Command not found
make.exe": *** [.validate-impl] Error 127
```

What could be the reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I installed the `MSYS` in the root of `C:/` and add the path to path environment in `Windows` also correct it in the `Netbeans`.

1. Download the MSYS from: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/mingw/MSYS-1.0.10.exe
2. Install it in `C:/`, and add the address in the o path: `C:\msys\1.0\bin`
3. Edit make.exe address in NetBeans: `Tools > Options > C/C++` in `Make Command`